# cpufreq scaling governors "ondemand" and "conservative" won't ignore nice load on AMD Ryzen CPUs

Tags: kernel, cpu, cpufreq

My kernel `5.11.0-22-generic` automatically loads the `cpufreq` scaling driver `acpi-cpufreq` and the scaling governor `schedutil` for my Ryzen 9 5900X. I enabled the setting `ignore_nice_load` after changing the scaling governor to either `ondemand` or `conservative` in order to fit my needs.

Accordingly after the changes everything looks correct; `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` returns `ondemand` or `conservative` for all CPUs and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load` returns 1.

Still after the change frequency scaling works as expected but the nice load is not ignored, i.e. BOINC processes running with a niceness of 19 cause an increase of the CPU frequency. Can you think of any way of ignoring nice load with a Ryzen 9 CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed by the new kernel version `5.13.0-21-generic` which I received after upgrading to Kubuntu 21.10.
When `ignore_nice_load` is set to `1` the CPU frequency is not scaling with BOINC running in the background.

Still the background load has a significant effect on the CPU temperature. At idle state the CPU temperature jumps from a bit less than 30 degrees Celsius before starting the BOINC daemon to a bit more than 50 degrees Celsius after starting the BOINC daemon.

Setting `ignore_nice_load` to `0` or `1` has a visible impact on CPU frequency but not really on the CPU temperature and hence power consumption. `ignore_nice_load` only improves my CPU temperature by 10 degrees Celsius, from a bit more than 60 degrees Celsius down to a bit more than 50 degrees Celsius.

My takeaway is that CPU power management improved dramatically over the years and my CPU never really sits idle but instead saves energy by sleeping whenever possible. This strips away the relevance of a tool like BOINC which is supposed to leverage idle CPU cycles.